# Is there a option to set Simple code blocks in one line across IDE's in Prettier?

Tags: intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, prettier

We want to use with different IDE's like VSCode and Intellij. To keep the code styles as close as possible we started now using prettier.

Unfortunately for easy code blocks prettier seems to work pretty differently between Intellij and VSCode.

Happens with Prettier in Intellij

```
public dispatch() {
}
```

vs. happens with prettier in VSCode

```
public dispatch() {}
```

I know there is the flag in Intellij "Simple blocks in one line" but it will be overwritten by the Prettier Plug-in.

Now I would ask if there is an option flag for the .prettierrc that can manage this behaviour? How would you solve this issue?

Comment: Seems there is related discussion on Prettier issue tracker: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/4125

Comment: I am also looking for the solution of same problem. Did you find anything?

Comment: No, unfortunatly not, we just worked with the problem that this will happen in our PRs.